# How to solve having to use an await method in ApiController initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, multi-tenant, asp.net-apicontroller

So I have a Base controller that all controllers inherit from, and it implements ApiController, in override initialize I have something like this:

```
    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var tenantId= requestUtils.GetFromHeader(controllerContext.Request);
        if (tenantId!= null)
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["tenantId"] = tenantId;
        else
            log4net.ThreadContext.Properties["tenantId"] = "default";
        await unitOfWork.SetTenantIdentifier(tenantIdentifier);
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    }
```

I need to set the tenantId for the unitofwork (since I have multitenant solution) and it needs an await before it (since I need to fetch something from the db)but I can't make Initialize an async Task so I'm trying to find a workaround or so.

Answer (score 1):

```
 //await unitOfWork.SetTenantIdentifier(tenantIdentifier);
 unitOfWork.SetTenantIdentifier(tenantIdentifier).Wait();
```

You should verify that there is no risk of deadlock on the Wait().

Comment: Why not use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, just to make sure any exceptions coming out of that method call aren't wrapped in an `AggregateException`?

Comment: Agreed :) but the guideline to avoid GetResult() is well past its prime. There's plenty of examples throughout Microsoft authored codebases (not Roslyn) that make use of it in sync-only contexts.

Comment: I'm not getting any results from both ways, no crashes(not even errors) but controllers not returning anything either, I'm guessing the request ended up stuck in someplace?

Comment: I'm not updating the database, I'm just setting the tenant to know which database to target. (different tenant = different connection string)

Comment: I fetch an encryption key every time I set a tenant (every tenant diff key) and to fetch it I need it to have an await.